# How to Convert int into a type Object within method; Java only

Tags: java

I'm trying to do my current project at my university, and I'm given an abstract class Value, and I'm needed to change basic types: int, string, object(map) and array(list) into Value. Value is made into an abstract constructor, and I need to create four different extended classes from Value. Each extended class will be able to get one of the types and convert into Value. added is the code I made for the get method, I want to know if it's possible to return the Value as it is below...

```
 public class Number extends Value {
     private Number k;

        public Number(Number k)
     {
            super();
            this.k = k;
    }
        public Value get(int i) {
            this.k=i;
            return this;    
        }
    }
```

The following is the super class given by the university...

```
    public abstract class Value 
{   
    public abstract Value get(int i);
    public abstract Value get(String s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some thing like this

```
   public abstract class Value {

    public abstract Value get(int i);

    public abstract Value get(String s);
  }

  public  class Number extends Value {
    private Number k;
    private Object o;

    public Number(Number k) {
      super();
      this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public Value get(int i) {
      this.k.o = i;
      return this;
    }

     @Override
     public Value get(String s) {
       this.k.o = s;
       return this;
     }
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, i'm not allowed to change the super class :/

Comment: you can add 'Object o' in Number class

Comment: You should add another constructor. Now you can only create new Number-Objects with an existing one. A public Number(int i) or something like that.

Comment: I just fixed the compile errors of the code did't change Xenheart implementation